# Airflow find DAG Runs with specific conf

Tags: airflow

I'm using **apache-airflow 1.10.10**.

My use case is: I have 4 DAGs, all of them triggers a common DAG named `"dag_common"` with different conf parameters using **BashOperator** after some work.

`airflow trigger_dag -c {"id":"1"} dag_common`

`airflow trigger_dag -c {"id":"2"} dag_common`

`airflow trigger_dag -c {"id":"3"} dag_common`

`airflow trigger_dag -c {"id":"4"} dag_common`

Inside these DAGs I have to wait for the triggered DAG to finish, how can I accomplish this?

`Dag1` has to wait until finish `dag_common` with conf `id=1`.
Is there any way to find all dag runs with specific conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a use case for [SubDAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=subdag#subdags): Implement `dag_common` as a subDAG and use `SubDagOperator()` in those four DAGs to run `dag_common`.